# Can't change the cursor in Tkinter

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

I have been trying to change the cursor in Tkinter. This is my code:

```
# explore_Tkinter.py

from Tkinter import *

def callback1(event):
    print "one clicked at", event.x, event.y

def callback2(event):
    print "two clicked at", event.x, event.y

root = Tk()

img = PhotoImage(file = "image002.gif")

canvas = Canvas(root, width = 1000, height = 700, cursor = "crosshair")
s1 = canvas.cget('cursor')
print "s1  ", s1

canvas.pack()
canvas.create_image(100, 200, image = img, anchor = 'nw')

canvas.bind("<Button-1>", callback1)
canvas.bind("<Button-2>", callback2)

mainloop()
```

When I run this the program prints

s1   crosshair

indicating that the cursor has been changed but the actual cursor on the image remains the same (an 'arrow').

What am doing wrong or not doing?

Comment: I can not reproduce the problem. The cursor is shown correctly, on the canvas and above the image (in case that makes a difference for you). Maybe an OS issue?

Answer (score -2):

I like to just use a plain cursor with my canvas something like this

```
import tkinter
tk = tkinter.Tk()
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(tk, cursor="diamond_cross", width=800, height=600, bg="white")
```

and there's many more cursors you can find from [here](http://docs.huihoo.com/tkinter/tkinter-reference-a-gui-for-python/cursors.html).

Comment: how does this answer the question? The code in the question is clearly setting the `cursor` attribute just like in your answer. I think the question is about why that's not working for them even though they are setting the `cursor` attribute.

Comment: I see I read it yea ok i'll have a look into it and try fix it. even though it was posted months back

Comment: hmm, on my system (Win7) Python 2.7m the cursor is a crosshair everywhere